# Why gcc and clang compiles to different "const" result for my program?

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, clang, constants

I was testing the behavior of "const" keyword under .c and .cpp, using gcc and clang.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int i=1;
    int *pi = (int *)(&i);
    *pi = 2;
    printf("i = %d *pi = %d\n",i,*pi);
    const int j=i;
    printf("j = %d\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

Using different compilers leads to different results:

```
$gcc testConst.c && ./a.out
i = 2 *pi = 2
j = 2

$clang testConst.c && ./a.out
i = 1 *pi = 2
j = 1
```

If I change the file from .c to .cpp, and use g++ to compile and run it, then the result is same as clang version

```
$g++ testConst.cpp && ./a.out
i = 1 *pi = 2
j = 1
```

I wish to know:

1. The meaning of 'const' in C and C++ are a bit different, so the result of same compiler gcc, could leads to different result?
2. Compiling the same .c file, gcc and clang have different result, which is correct, or this is undefined behavior? Any C/C++ standard statements that could explain this?

Comment: Modifying a const variable is UB. Also this has been asked a lot of times before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **undefined behavior** to modify a `const` variable.  It could even be that this:

```
*pi = 2;
```

Sets your integer to 9999.  Or crashes the program.

Even once you've compiled the program, if you run it four times and get four different results, you will have no standing to complain.  That's the beauty of undefined behavior.